What is a currently working solution for React Native accessing location?
I have a react native app that I started developing a few years ago. I just got back to it and I cannot get react-native-location-enabler to work. If it's not an event emmitter warning it's a class passed as interface. Ugh
All location stuff was working perfectly before and now I have tried many things including Expo which I really don't want to use anyway.
Per the research I have tried I don't think it works with the latest react version.
I am using Typescript.
Can someone please help me discover a working solution for accessing, turning on, and utilizing location on the phone within the app?
I have tried everything I know and other plug-ins.

I'm using @react-native-community/geolocation

Accessing and Enabling Location Services in React Native
If you’re facing issues with react-native-location-enabler and are looking for a reliable solution to access and enable location services in your React Native app using TypeScript, you can utilize react-native-maps along with react-native-permissions for managing permissions.
Step-by-step Guide:

Install Required Packages:
First, ensure you have the necessary packages installed. You can do this by running:
npm install react-native-maps react-native-permissions

Make sure you also link the libraries if you're not using auto-linking (React Native < 0.60):
react-native link react-native-maps
react-native link react-native-permissions


Setup Permissions:
You need to configure the permissions for location access in your app.
For iOS:

Open your Info.plist and add the following keys:

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to show nearby places.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need your location to provide better services.</string>

For Android:

In your AndroidManifest.xml, add the following permissions:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


Request Location Permissions:
Use react-native-permissions to request location permissions in your component.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const [locationGranted, setLocationGranted] = useState(false);
    const [region, setRegion] = useState({
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    {
                        title: "Location Permission",
                        message: "This app requires access to your location.",
                        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
                        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
                        buttonPositive: "OK"
                    }
                );
                setLocationGranted(granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED);
            } else {
                // For iOS, you can directly set locationGranted to true
                setLocationGranted(true);
            }
        };
        requestLocationPermission();
    }, []);

    // Optionally add a method to get the user's current location
    const getCurrentLocation = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                setRegion({
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                });
            },
            (error) => console.log(error),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
        );
    };

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {locationGranted ? (
                <MapView style={{ flex: 1 }} region={region}>
                    <Marker coordinate={region} />
                </MapView>
            ) : (
                <Text>Location permission denied</Text>
            )}
            <Button title="Get Current Location" onPress={getCurrentLocation} />
        </View>
    );
};

export default App;



Key Points:

Permissions: Always request location permissions before trying to access the device's location.
Handling Location: Use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to fetch the current location once permissions are granted.
Testing on Physical Devices: Remember that location services may not work properly on emulators; testing on a real device is essential.

This approach leverages react-native-maps for displaying maps and react-native-permissions for handling permissions, providing a clean and effective way to manage location services in your app.
Feel free to modify the code according to your app's requirements!
Make sure to test your implementation thoroughly and check the official documentation for any updates on the libraries you are using. Good luck with your project!
[react-native] [typescript] [location] [geolocation]

But how are you checking to see if location is turned on? I need to check if it's on and have the user turn it on if it's not on

First, you'll want to check if you have permission to access the user's location. If permission is granted, you can then call the getCurrentPosition function. If the user's location services are turned off, the app will prompt them to enable it. If location services are already enabled, the app can directly retrieve the user's location.
